# Save data from localStorage to csv

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Is it possible to save the data from local storage to a csv file?

First i want to fill in a html form, after that Some pictures are shown with rating buttons. 
My idea is to store all the input in the local storage and then save all to a csv file (this should be saved on a server)
Is there any way to save all the data at the end to a csv file?

Comment: _"this should be saved on a server"_ - Which server-side language(s) are you using? You can certainly submit the data from the browser to the server (possibly with Ajax), but how you'd make the server save a CSV would depend on the server technology/language.

Comment: I thougt of using php to save it on the server

Answer (score 4):

Using Blob (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Blob) this seems achievable. First generate the file from the local store then blast it off to the server however you like. This should get you going in the right direction:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>CSV Export</title>
<script>
    function exportData() {
        var item = localStorage.csv=",what you want in the CSV,";

        var ary = localStorage.getItem( "csv" ); //csv as a string
        var blob = new Blob([ary], {type: "text/csv"});
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var a = document.querySelector("#results"); // id of the <a> element to render the download link
        a.href = url;
        a.download = "file.csv";

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="exportData()">Download CSV</button><br>
    <a id="results">CSV from local store</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Getting the file onto the server is another matter but you should be able to tweak this and use PHP, .NET or whatever else.